# Storing the unknown contents of a macro in a clist

Tags: macros, spacing, expl3

[edited after egreg's answer] I want to store macros and their contents as pairs `macro {macro contents}` in a clist. The macros will be defined elsewhere, by the user or in another package, and will contain either numbers or mathematical formulas. The question is, given only the macro name, e.g. `\mymacro`, how can I see the contents stored in `\mymacro`? In the following example, `\exp_not:f` succeeds when the macro definition contains a leading space, but fails when it doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

% space before \sin
\NewDocumentCommand \myloosemacro {} { \sin(\pi/6) }
% no space before \sin
\NewDocumentCommand \mytightmacro {} {\sin(\pi/6)}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__storemacros:N #1
  { \clist_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { #1 { \exp_not:f #1 } } }
  
\clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist

\__storemacros:N \myloosemacro
\__storemacros:N \mytightmacro

\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

This shows that `\l_tmpa_clist` contains the pairs:

```
\myloosemacro {\sin (\pi /6) }
\mytightmacro {\protect \sin  (\pi /6)}
```

The first is the desired result, the second contains an extra unwanted token -- not present in the definition of the macro. By uncommenting `\usepackage{amsmath}`, things get worse. The second of these becomes `\mytightmacro {\protect \qopname  \relax o{sin}(\pi /6)}` with many extra tokens not present at time of definition. As mentioned earlier, the macros will come from other packages or user input, so I have no control over the presence or absence of an initial space.

Comment: Why use `\exp_not:f` to trim leading space? It seems more appropriate to use the `\tl_trim_spaces:<variants>`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the macro contents stored in the clist in the form used when the macro was defined. When there is a leading space `\exp_not:f` gives the desired result. It expands the macro but stops expanding at the leading space, giving the desired result. With no leading space `\sin` gets expanded resulting in all the extra unwanted tokens.

Comment: If you don't know how the macros are defined, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong tools.

With `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{<code>}`, you're defining a `\protected` macro, that will pass unchanged through `x`- or `e`-expansion. However, the `\protected` has no effect in `f`-expansion.

If you do `\show\myloosemacro`, you see that the macro is defined as

```
> \myloosemacro=\protected macro:
->\__cmd_start_expandable:nNNNNn {}\myloosemacro  \myloosemacro  \myloosemacro code ?{}.
```

and the replacement text is stored in `\myloosemacro code` (yes, with a space in the name)

```
? i\expandafter\show\csname myloosemacro code\endcsname
> \myloosemacro code=\protected\long macro:
-> \sin (\pi /6) .
```

If I do the same with `\mytightmacro`, I see

```
? i\expandafter\show\csname mytightmacro code\endcsname
> \mytightmacro code=\protected\long macro:
->\sin (\pi /6).
```

Here you see the initial space in the former.

You apply `\exp_not:f` which does recursive one level expansions, stopping when an unexpandable token is found (and ignoring it if it's a space). The  tokens in the definition of `\myloosemacro` are designed to produce nothing in `f`-expansion, until arriving to `\myloosemacro code ?{}`, which only produces the replacement text. Here's where the space is gobbled, because it stops the `f`-expansion.

Essentially the same happens with `\mytightmacro`, but with an important difference: there is no space that blocks the `f`-expansion, so `\sin` is expanded. And `\show\sin` tells you that the definition is

```
> \sin=macro:
->\protect \sin  .
```

(with a trailing space in the name of the last command). You're lucky, because at call time, `\protect` is `\relax` and so it blocks `f`-expansion (but it's not ignored).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{mm}
 {
  \tl_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% space before \sin
\definevar \myloosemacro { \sin(\pi/6) }
% no space before \sin
\definevar \mytightmacro {\sin(\pi/6)}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__storemacros:N #1
  { \clist_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { \exp_not:N #1 { \tl_trim_spaces:e { \exp_not:V #1 } } } }
  
\clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist

\__storemacros:N \myloosemacro
\__storemacros:N \mytightmacro

\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

will show

```
The comma list \l_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\myloosemacro {\sin (\pi /6)}}
>  {\mytightmacro {\sin (\pi /6)}}.
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The discussion of f-expansion is helpful, but my question wasn't clear enough. I have edited it. Your `\definevar` takes two arguments, #1, #2, but I am given only #1. That is the problem. How do I get #2, the contents of #1, to store in the clist?

Answer (score 1):

```
The comma list \l_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\myloosemacro { \sin (\pi /6) }}
>  {\mytightmacro {\sin (\pi /6)}}
>  {\myoldmacro {\frac {1}{2}}}.
```

is  produced from

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

% space before \sin
\NewDocumentCommand \myloosemacro {} { \sin(\pi/6) }
% no space before \sin
\NewDocumentCommand \mytightmacro {} {\sin(\pi/6)}

\newcommand\myoldmacro{\frac{1}{2}}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__storemacros:N #1
  {
\ifcsname \exp_after:wN \use_none:n\token_to_str:N#1~ code\endcsname
\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN
 \clist_put_right:Nn
\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN
        \l_tmpa_clist
\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN {
\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN
            #1
\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN 
{ \csname \exp_after:wN \use_none:n\token_to_str:N#1~ code\endcsname } } 
\else
\exp_after:wN \clist_put_right:Nn \exp_after:wN
        \l_tmpa_clist \exp_after:wN { \exp_after:wN
            #1 \exp_after:wN { #1 } } 
\fi}
  
\clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist

\__storemacros:N \myloosemacro
\__storemacros:N \mytightmacro
\__storemacros:N \myoldmacro

\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: A level of virtuosity out of my league! Thank you, it does exactly what I was looking for (although I am startled that it should require such a construction).

Comment: @AndrewParsloe the complication is just because I did not do what you asked. "how can I see the contents stored in \mymacro" would show `\__cmd_start_expandable:nNNNNn {}\mytightmacro  \mytightmacro  \mytightmacro 
code ?{}`  which is what `\mytightmacro` expands to. The question really is why don't you want that in the clist, what is the real use case?

Comment: I have a package `numerica` which parses mathematical formulas written in LaTeX and turns them into `l3fp` form to be evaluated. The parser recognizes e.g. `\sin` or `\sum` but not the "hidden" commands (like `\protect`) that result when they are expanded.

Comment: @AndrewParsloe `{\def\sin{sin}\def\pi{pi}\typeout{\fpeval{\mytightmacro}}}` ?

Comment: I think we are at cross-purposes here. A user may include their own macro in a formula. The macro might contain a number or a sub-formula. The parser needs access to the sub-formula as  written in LaTeX. That was the origin of my enquiry.

Comment: yes but my point is `\__cmd_start_expandable:nNNNNn {}\mytightmacro  \mytightmacro  \mytightmacro  code ?{}` may look ugly but  if it is for machine rather than human consumption, as it expands to `\sin(\pi/6)` does it matter? as the previous comment shows, it can be used as is in expansion contexts such as fpeval without the complicaton of the code in the answer which just makes a "nicer looking" form for `\clist_show:N`

Comment: StackExchange is suggesting this exchange should be continued elsewhere. `numerica` is on CTAN. My email address is in the documentation if you wish to continue. I would be happy to do so.

Comment: if you get that message it does not mean go off-site, click on _automatically move this discussion to chat?_ and it starts a new chat thread off this main post page. But probably we are done:-) @AndrewParsloe